How can we prove the derivatives of displacement?
According to this, in physics, the first derivative is velocity and the second derivative is acceleration. I should be able to do simple things like this.
Here's my attempt with a function $f(t)=2t$ where $t$ is the time driven. Every $t$ seconds driven, results in $2t$ meters. The derivative of $2x$ is $2$. Velocity is defined as distance over time $\rightarrow \frac{d}{t}$ so we have $\frac{2t}{t} = 2$. This works for a simple function.
Now to extend from the last part, the second derivative of $2x$ is $0$ and the acceleration is $0$ by inspection. This also works.
How can we prove that the first derivative for any function is velocity and the second derivative for any function is acceleration?
(note: please comment if not all functions have this property, also I know some functions do not have derivatives)
and let me know if the tags are appropriate :) thanks!! all help is appreciated
I saw here (the title is "acceleration as the second derivative of displacement function") so it's only for displacement functions... don't know what that means but maybe thats somehow related

yes i searched up what a displacement function is, still confused

to clarify, i dont know how to generalize what i did with $y=2x$ for a general function, lets say $f(x)$

The average speed is $d/t$. The instantaneous velocity is $\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$

does that mean what i did is wrong or is it right for the wrong reason? @Andrei

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community I bolded my question... I have no idea how to prove what I wrote above.

The definition of the instantaneous velocity is the derivative of the position with respect to time.

In some sense, you can take the first and second derivatives as definitions of velocity and acceleration, in which case there's nothing to prove. I sense that that's not what you mean, though. You should probably start by defining average velocity and acceleration and then, using limits, define the instantaneous velocity and acceleration.

@H.sapiensrex i'm wondering why the first and second derivatives are velocity and acceleration, a logical explanation would be nice instead of a formal proof

should I just accept that it's true? I want to know why, it's like the sum of the angles in a triangle. When we're young we just accept that it's true but when we get into geometry, we see a proof. am I going to eventually find out why or do I just accept its true? like an axiom

What is the definition of velocity and acceleration in a general case? You have for velocity distance divided by time. But what distance and what time? Did you measure distance traveled in the last hour, last minute, last second?

@Andrei does it matter? $y=2x$ is linear so the distance or time doesn't matter. the distance is equal to two times the time.

For that case it does not matter. But it will matter if you want to generalize it. So how would you define velocity if $x=5t^3+2t+3$? Do you measure the position with respect to the position at $t=0$? Why? Think of the case when the policeman stops a driver for speeding. "Since lase night (10 hours ago), I've traveled only 10 miles. So my speed is 1 mile per hour." This justification will not work.

@wasu in this instance, "formal" and "logical" explanations are the same thing. I believe you meant "intuitive", and that's a much more difficult ask because our modern analytic definitions of the terms were derived by expressly ignoring intuition (think of classic paradoxes like Zeno's paradox)

When we establish a coordinate system for space, this allows us to identify the points of space with triples $(x,y,z)$ of numbers. These coordinates indicate that the point in question is displaced from the origin by a (signed) distance $x$ in the direction of the positive $x$-axis, a distance $y$ in the direction of the positive $y$-axis, and a distance $z$ in the direction of the positive $z$-axis.
If for each time $t$ we plot the position $p$ of some moving particle, this defines a function giving the coordinates of the particle at each time $t: (x(t), y(t), z(t))$. Because the coordinates locate the point by its displacement from the origin, this is called the displacement function.
Now, the set of all coordinates, which we call $\Bbb R^3$ is a vector space:
We can add and subtract coordinates: $(a,b,c) + (x,y,z) = (a + x, b + y, c + z)$ and multiply and divide them by scalars:$u(x,y,z) = (ux, uy, uz)$. In particular, if $r(t)$ is the displacement function of some particle. At some time $t_0$, the particle is at some location $r(t_0) = (x(t_0), y(t_0), z(t_0))$ and later at time $t_1$, it is at $r(t_1) = (x(t_1), y(t_1), z(t_1))$. In that time, the particle is displaced from its location at $t_0$ by a vector $$r(t_1) - r(t_0) = (x(t_1) - x(t_0), y(t_1) - y(t_0), z(t_1) - z(t_0))$$
The distance by which it is displaced is the length of this vector: $$d = \sqrt{(x(t_1) - x(t_0))^2 + (y(t_1) - y(t_0))^2+ (z(t_1) - z(t_0))^2}$$
The definition you have for velocity is not quite correct: Over the time interval $[t_0, t_1]$, the average velocity of the particle is defined to be the displacement (not distance) between the particles beginning and ending locations, divided by the length of the time interval:
$$v_\text{avg}(t_0, t_1) = \frac{r(t_1) - r(t_0)}{t_1 - t_0}$$
This is called the average because it takes no account of how the particle behaved in the middle of the time interval. Its only concern is the final outcome. The particle that moved directly and constantly from one point to the other and the particle that went on a wild world tour, then went to the destination and sat there unmoving until the plodder finally arrived will both have the same average velocity.
If we want to get a better idea of how the particles behaved, we can break the time interval down into smaller subintervals and examine the average velocity on each of them. If the subintervals are small enough, they will detect the differences between the two particles, and the smaller they are, the more accurately, they will describe each particle's behavior. But other than being greater than $0$, there is no restriction on how small the time intervals can be. But a time interval of length $0$ is not possible, as we cannot divide by $0$. So if we want to know the behavior of the particles at time $t_0$, not just over some interval, we need to take a limit. We define the velocity  of the particle to be the limit of its average velocity as the time interval goes to $0$:
$$v(t_0) = \lim_{t_1 \to t_0} \frac{r(t_1) - r(t_0)}{t_1 - t_0}$$
This is sometimes called the "instantaneous velocity" to distinguish it from the average velocity. But usually, it is just called the velocity. But notice that expression is also exactly the definition of the derivative of $r(t)$ at $t_0$: $$v(t_0) = \frac{dr}{dt}(t_0) = \dot r(t_0)$$
Indeed, it is exactly this need to express instantaneous velocity that led to the derivative being defined in the first place.
Now that we have a function that gives the velocity as a function of time, we can do the same thing with how the velocity changes with respect to time. The average acceleration is defined to be the change in velocity over a time interval divided by the length of the interval:
$$a_\text{avg}(t_0, t_1) = \frac{v(t_1) - v(t_0)}{t_1 - t_0}$$
and once again, to find out what is occurring at $t_0$ itself instead of over some interval, we take the limit as the interval length shrinks to $0$. The acceleration is defined to be the limit value:
$$a(t_0) = \lim_{t_1 \to t_0} \frac{v(t_1) - v(t_0)}{t_1 - t_0} = \dot v(t_0) = \frac{d}{dt}\dot r(t_0) = \ddot r(t_0)$$
These are definitions. The description is to show you the intuition that led to the definitions. They are not proofs because the only "proof" needed is to say these are definitions of velocity and acceleration. You only have to prove something if you had some other way of giving a number to the concepts of velocity and acceleration - in which case you would want to prove that the two means give the same value. But without a different way to compare to, there is nothing to prove.

thank you! this is what I was looking for.
